# python argparse multiple arguments processing

Tags: python, argparse

A beginner here. Need some help on argparse. Below is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import re
import string

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-a', '--add', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*') 
p.add_argument('-d', '--delete', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*') 
args = p.parse_args()
add_List = args.add 
del_List = args.delete

addN = "adding.."
delN = "deleting.."

def test(what):
    for i in range(5):
        print what

######### expected output: "adding.." 5 times 
for i in add_List:
    test(addN)

######### expected output: "deleting.." 5 times 
for i in deL_List:
    test(delN)
```

What I basically want is that when the script is run as,

> 1. ./script -a 1.1.1.1:99:na1 it should print "adding.." 5 times
> 2. ./script -d 1.1.1.1:99:na1 it should print "deleting.." 5 times

Please do not mind the arguments given with the script cos they will be processed separately. I just want to understand the most efficient way to use argparse with  appropriate conditionals in a scenario like this. Further it would be great if I can print out a sensible usage guide as well.

Comment: take a look at [click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/)

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov click looks promising. Thanks a lot. Id still love to get it done with argparse so please ammend the code if you know your way around argparse. thanks.

Comment: What's the problem?  Does it work?  Produce what you want, if not what is wrong?  What do you mean by sensible `usage`?  Don't worry about 'efficiency'.  This code is run once at the start of your script.  Your users are only going to provide a few strings, not hundreds; `add_List` and `deL_List` will be short.

Comment: I've mentioned what I want. When executed with -d it should print "deleting" and with -a "adding".

Comment: But what does it do NOW?

Comment: @hpaulj only prints adding. Anyways let's wait for other users to answer if you are to throw more questions at me. Said in the question I'm a beginner. Thanks for trying to help out anyways.

Comment: That's not it works here.  I have run your code, and found some problems.  I can make suggestions on to fix it.  But you haven't answered my most basic questions.  I want you to provide a complete question.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. I really have no idea as to how much more I can elaborate on my basic question. It's jus that I'm trying to figure processing multiple options. Here "-a" and "d"

Comment: Isn't that just a typo ? deL_list instead of del_list ? See my answer...

Comment: See my answer for the kind of information that you should be providing.  You should have caught the `deL` typo.  You should have told us about the problem with `None`.  That doesn't even touch on the question of what is a good `usage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to me that it is just a typo. On row 26 del_list instead of del_List.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import re
import string

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-a', '--add', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')
p.add_argument('-d', '--delete', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')
args = p.parse_args()
add_List = args.add or [] #['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']
del_List = args.delete or [] #['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']

addN = "adding.."
delN = "deleting.."

def test(what):
    for i in range(5):
        print(what)

######### expected output: "adding.." 5 times
for i in add_List:
    test(addN)

######### expected output: "deleting.." 5 times
for i in del_List:
    test(delN)
```

Output

```
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
```

Args

```
--delete 123 --add 456
```

Comment: What if he doesn't give `--delete` at all?

Comment: @Diego Amicabile Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When I first run your code as posted I get

```
1550:~/mypy$ python stack43690807.py -a 1.1.1.1:99:na1
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack43690807.py", line 23, in <module>
    for i in deL_List:
NameError: name 'deL_List' is not defined
```

If I correct the typo  (upper case L)

```
1819:~/mypy$ python stack43690807.py -a 1.1.1.1:99:na1
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack43690807.py", line 23, in <module>
    for i in del_List:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here the problem is that the default is `None`.  `for i in None:` does not work. So we either need to test for `None`, e.g.

```
if add_List is not None:
   for i in add_List:
   ....
```

or we need change the default to something like `default=[]`.  Also I"ve added a `print(args)` statement, so we get a clearer idea of what the parser produces.

```
1819:~/mypy$ python stack43690807.py -a 1.1.1.1:99:na1
Namespace(add=['1.1.1.1:99:na1'], delete=[])
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
adding..
1820:~/mypy$ python stack43690807.py -d 1.1.1.1:99:na1
Namespace(add=[], delete=['1.1.1.1:99:na1'])
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
deleting..
```

---

```
import argparse


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-a', '--add', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*', default=[])
# add default parameter
p.add_argument('-d', '--delete', help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*', default=[])
args = p.parse_args()
print(args)
add_List = args.add #['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']
del_List = args.delete #['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']

addN = "adding.."
delN = "deleting.."

def test(what):
    for i in range(5):
        print what

######### expected output: "adding.." 5 times
for i in add_List:
    test(addN)

######### expected output: "deleting.." 5 times
for i in del_List:     # <== correct typo
    test(delN)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Please if you don't mind can yo post the full code for clarity? Having some troubles understanding.